# Does core config support adding ad users?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

Does the open source core configurator tool for windows server support the addition, editing and removing of users from AD?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on http://www.codeplex.com/CoreConfig I'd have to say "no". However, you can easily use  other commands to manage users, either from PowerShell or the regular Windows command line. For example, joeware's admod tool will let you do a number of related tasks.